# Apple ARKitExample Code

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I just downloaded the ARKitExample Projekt(Placing Objects). Unfortunately there are some bugs. I am new to swift so I don't know how to fix them. Could someone help me out? 
I keep getting the error(file: Utility.swift):

Nil is not compatible with expected argument type '[String: Any]'

code:

```
extension UIImage {
    func inverted() -> UIImage? {
        guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: self) else {
            return nil
        }
        return UIImage(ciImage: ciImage.applyingFilter("CIColorInvert", withInputParameters: nil))
    }
```

The return UIImage is the problem. The last parameter: "withInputParameters: nil" is the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems the signature for the `CIImage applyingFilter(_:withInputParameters:)` method changed as of iOS 11.

It was:

```
func applyingFilter(_ filterName: String, withInputParameters params: [String : Any]?) -> CIImage
```

It is now (as of iOS 11):

```
func applyingFilter(_ filterName: String, parameters params: [String : Any]) -> CIImage
```

Since you are playing with ARKit you must be using iOS 11 so you need to change your code to:

```
extension UIImage {
    func inverted() -> UIImage? {
        guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: self) else {
            return nil
        }
        return UIImage(ciImage: ciImage.applyingFilter("CIColorInvert", parameters: [:]))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixed the problem.

Comment: It didn't work to me, I changed the code to:
func inverted() -> UIImage? {
        guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: self) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let inverted =  ciImage.applyingFilter("CIColorInvert", withInputParameters: [:])
        
        return UIImage(cgImage: CIContext(options: nil).createCGImage(inverted, from: inverted.extent)!)
    }